# query explain output

Tags: mysql, query-performance, mariadb

I have a table with many rows. And some queries are slow, they use indexes but the queries still cost a lot of time, how can I optimize these queries?
Cluster, temporary table ... ?

```
CREATE TABLE `fn_movim_finan` (
  `id` decimal(20,4) NOT NULL,
  `id_receber` decimal(15,4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `id_receberx` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `documento` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `data` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `pdesconto` decimal(5,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `vdesconto` decimal(15,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `pacrescimo` decimal(5,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `vacrescimo` decimal(15,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `credito` decimal(15,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `historico` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `id_movim_finan` decimal(15,4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tipo_lanc` enum('M','P','R','D','C','AC','AF','T') DEFAULT NULL,
  `filial_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ultima_atualizacao` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `id_franquia_fn_movim_finam` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `idx` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `debito` decimal(15,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `data_recebimento` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `id_conta` decimal(15,4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `id_automatico` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ultima_atualizacao_original` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `conciliado` enum('S','N') DEFAULT NULL,
  `conciliado_extrato` text,
  `conciliado_fn` mediumtext,
  `conta_` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `id_fornecedor` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `chave_recebimento_unico` varchar(70) DEFAULT NULL,
  `id_renegociacao` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `id_movim_cheque` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `id_operador` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `id_ajuste_estoque` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `id_motivo_desconto` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `id_lote_retorno` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `id_classe_financeira` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `id_conta_class_finan_a` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `id_conciliacao_lote` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `id_grade_contabil` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cancelamento` varchar(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `id_movimento_produto_comodato` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `id_receber` (`id_receber`),
  KEY `idx` (`idx`),
  KEY `ultima_atualizacao` (`ultima_atualizacao`),
  KEY `id_automatico` (`id_automatico`),
  KEY `ultima_atualizacao_original` 
(`ultima_atualizacao_original`),
  KEY `filial_id` (`filial_id`),
  KEY `tipo_lan_data` (`tipo_lanc`,`data`),
  KEY `filial_idx` (`filial_id`,`idx`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=44539365 DEFAULT 
CHARSET=latin1;
```

average row size: 550 bytes

number rows: 25.833.188

Query:

```
SELECT filial_id,
data,
YEAR(data) as ano,
MONTH(data) as mes,
IFNULL(sum(fn_movim_finan.vacrescimo - 
fn_movim_finan.vdesconto), 0) as diferenca,
IFNULL(sum(fn_movim_finan.vacrescimo), 0) as acrescimo,
IFNULL(sum(fn_movim_finan.vdesconto), 0) as desconto
FROM fn_movim_finan
WHERE tipo_lanc = 'R'
AND data >= '2021-11-01' AND data <= '2022-10-31'
GROUP BY filial_id, ano, mes 
ORDER BY filial_id ASC, data ASC;
```

runtime:1 minute

Explain output

[image]

Comment: You're going to have to provide more detail - table structure, average row size, the queries you're trying to optimize, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(`tipo_lanc`,`data`) is a good index.  However, since the `WHERE` may be fetching most of the table, the index may not be used.  It is using that index.  The `key_len=2` is deceptive; it is probably actually using both columns.  If the resultset really has 6M rows, then 1 minute is rather fast.

This one suggestion may speed up things.  Making the `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY` compatible will eliminate a sort (of 6M rows):

```
GROUP BY  filial_id,     ano,     mes
ORDER BY  filial_id ASC, ano ASC, mes ASC
```

If I understand your query and the Spanish(?) words, changing `ORDER BY` will get exactly the same result.

Consider

```
      AND  data >= '2021-11-01'
      AND  data <= '2022-10-31'
```

-->

```
      AND  data >= '2021-11-01'
      AND  data  < '2021-11-01' + INTERVAL 1 YEAR
```

That will avoid computing leap days, etc.

26M rows in the table?  How many rows in the resultset?  How much RAM do you have?  What is the value of `innodb_buffer_pool_size`?  (There could be an issue here.)

**More** (based on Comment, below)

1. Fetching 2.9M rows based on the index will take most of the time.
2. Doing the SUM will take some time.
3. The `ORDER BY` for the final 1K row at the end will take very little time.  (My suggestion of making `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY` the same won't have much effect.)

The buffer_pool is big enough that running the query a second time may run faster.  (But that is probably a small consolation.)

There is no good solution for this type of query on this type of table.

If queries like this are common, then building and maintaining a [*Summary Table*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/summarytables) may be the best solution.  It would have subtotals for each tipo_lanc for each day.  Then summing the sums and further grouping and ordering will run much faster -- perhaps 5 to 10 times as fast.

Comment: Yes, 26 million rows in the table.
The resultset 1082 rows, but in the filters that the query uses to sun and group we have a total of 2.892.079 rows.
    select count(*) from fn_movim_finan WHERE tipo_lanc = 'R'
    AND data >= '2021-11-01' AND data <= '2022-10-31';
Total RAM in the server 32 G
inoodb_buffer_pool_size 16 GB, because there are other services on ther server like php, elasticsearch :/.

Comment: @RafaelBusz - I provide another solution.

Comment: I understand thank you.
A question about the summary tables part. 
"Plan A: "While inserting" rows into the Fact table, augment the Summary Table(s). This is simple, and workable for a smaller DW database (under 10 Fact table rows per second). For larger DW databases, Plan A likely to be too costly to be practical."
Would this part be better done with a trigger or in php code or... ?

Comment: @RafaelBusz - It depends.  How does the data come in?  One row at a time for a variety of sources?  Or big clumps of rows at a time?  And other details that might lead to giving you a more specific answer.

Comment: I have a task that fetches data from another database with an interval of one hour. Total rows is 1000 to 5000 thousand rows per hour.
Creating a summary table the queries are 100x faster, the problem is that I have deletion of rows in the parent table and I need to update this in the summary table with update.
For insert and update I can do with the IODKU.

Comment: -- CREATE TABLE fn_movim_finan_resumo
    CREATE TABLE `fn_movim_finan_resumo` (
     `filial_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
     `data` date NOT NULL,
 `credito` decimal(15,2) NOT NULL,
 `vacrescimo` decimal(15,2) NOT NULL,
 `vdesconto` decimal(15,2) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (filial_id,data)) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

Comment: INSERT INTO fn_movim_finan_resumo (filial_id,data,credito,vacrescimo,vdesconto)
VALUES(2,'2022-01-01',10,10,10)
ON duplicate key UPDATE credito = credito + VALUES(credito),
vacrescimo = vacrescimo + VALUES(vacrescimo),
vdesconto = vdesconto + VALUES(vdesconto);

Comment: @RafaelBusz - Please start a new Question; the "Comments" does not lend itself to anything more than brief Q&A.  Please provide the `CREATE` for the summary table, and  more details on which rows need deleting from it.